# save image file with increment at the end of file name

Tags: java, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxtV3.png)

**please someone help me "To save an image file with increment at end of file name" like("image 1.jpg , image 2.jpg , etc..")**

**here is my code**

please some help me to make this,i am new learner to android-studio.

```
private File saveBitMap(Context context, View drawView) {

    File pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"Frames");

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
        if(!isDirectoryCreated) {
            Log.i("ATG", "Can't create directory to save the image");
        }
        return null;
    }
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() +File.separator+"Frame"+ System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);
    Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(drawView);
    try {
        pictureFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oStream);
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue saving the image.");
    }
    scanGallery( context,pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    return pictureFile;
}
```

Comment: Also newbie to English!

Comment: You can inspect the names of the saved files that currently exist and build a new one from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question properly then, I assume you want your `pictureFile` name to be appended by an integer (in auto-incrementing fashion).

You could do that by maintaining a global variable as `int imageCount = 1`

and then appending it while creating `fileName`

```
int imageCount = 1;

private File saveBitMap(Context context, View drawView) {

    File pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"Frames");

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
        if(!isDirectoryCreated) {
            Log.i("ATG", "Can't create directory to save the image");
        }
        return null;
    }
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() +File.separator+"Frame"+ System.currentTimeMillis()+""+(imageCount++)+".jpg";
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);
    Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(drawView);
    try {
        pictureFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oStream);
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue saving the image.");
    }
    scanGallery( context,pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    return pictureFile;
}
```

Comment: @Shaik glad it worked, Would you mind accepting it as the Answer.

Comment: @Shaik bro there is an option to accept it as the answer. Look at the left of the answer, click on it.
((click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in))

Comment: bro, I have some issue with my app , please send "Hii" to my Gmail - " developershaikzz@gmail.com " and i'll send the source code to your mail please help me

Comment: bro send "hii" to mail "developershaikzz@gmail.com"